# How do I use the same parameter multiple times in my Query using JPA?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

How do I use a parameter multiple times in the same query? Here is my Query:

```
@Query(value = """
        SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = ? or last_name = ?
        """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(String name);
```

I need to use the "name" parameter twice in the query, how do I do that?

*NOTE: This is just a dummy example, for me to understand the logic.*

**I've tried this:**

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = ?1 or last_name = ?1
    """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(String name);
```

I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

**I've also tried this:**

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = :name or last_name = :name
    """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(@Param("name") String name);
```

This gives me the same error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Comment: do you have the exception on the provided queries or on some other queries you are not sharing?

Comment: @Ben, did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = ?1 or last_name = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(String name);
```

There `?1` refers to the first arg.

You can also use a specific name to represent it. Like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = :myName or last_name = :myName", nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(@Param(name = "myName") String name);
```

Hope helpul for you.

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I've updated the question.

Comment: By the way, if I use the parameter only once, then both methods work.. it's only when I use it twice.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, using your exemple  :

```
@Query(value = """
        Declare @Name Varchar(max) = :name
        SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = @Name or last_name = @Name
        """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ?1 as reference to first parameter multiple times. Example based on your code:

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = ?1 or last_name = ?1
    """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(String name);
```

Or you can use named parameters multiple times:

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = :name or last_name = :name
    """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I've updated the question.

Comment: By the way, if I use the parameter only once, then both methods work.. it's only when I use it twice.

Comment: Maybe parameter and field type doesn't match?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use two params as below?

```
@Query(value = "
SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = :fname or 
last_name = :lname
", nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(@Param("fname") String 
fnamee,@Param("lname") String lname  );
```

Or you can use repository method as below.

```
List<Person>  findByFirstNameOrLastNamee(String firstName, 
String lastName);
```

Pass same name twice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using a Query But when using JPA syntax It's so simple you can do it by using the @Param annotation

```
List<Person>  findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(
@Param("yourParam")String word1,
@Param("TheSameParamName")String word2)
```

Spring will use the same parameter name.

EDITED

i suppose you can modify your code like this following the same idea

```
@Query(value = """
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name = :name or last_name = :name1
    """, nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> findPerson(
@Param("name") String name,
@Param("name") String name1);
```

Notice that you just need to change the secound variable name and using the @Param annotation the same value of @Param("name") will be used.